# Any tips or documentation on Installing Chef Client: 14.0.202 ? Seems fairly new

Tags: chef-infra

Installing `Chef Client: 14.0.202` on Debian 9 clients as the first clients on a Debian 9  `Chef-server-core  = 12.17.15-1`

I'm wanting to dive in but I'd like to study it first. Not finding what I need on https://chef.io.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to be far more specific but you can find the general install instructions at https://docs.chef.io/install_bootstrap.html and the later sibling pages. There are no special instructions for Chef 14, other than being a new major rev, it's the same package as always.